# How to check if the image file existed in mvc?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

`DoctorID` and image at the particular location is present only if condition should be work otherwise else should be work..

Currently it be check only `DoctorID` how to check the image file present or not

```
@if (doctor.DoctorID > 0)
{

    <img src="@Url.Content(String.Format("~/Doctor/" + doctor.DoctorID + ".png"))" />
}
else
{ 
<img src="~/img/avatar-sign.png" />
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i guess my answer

```
 @if (File.Exists(Server.MapPath("/Doctor/" + doctor.DoctorID + ".png")) && doctor.DoctorId > 0)
                            {

                                <img src="@Url.Content(String.Format("~/Doctor/" + doctor.DoctorID + ".png"))" />
                            }
                            else
                            { 
                            <img src="~/img/avatar-sign.png" />
                            }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 @if (File.Exists(Server.MapPath("/Doctor/" + doctor.DoctorID + ".png")) && doctor.DoctorId > 0)
                        {

                            <img src="@Url.Content(String.Format("~/Doctor/" + doctor.DoctorID + ".png"))" />
                        }
                        else
                        { 
                        <img src="~/img/avatar-sign.png" />
                        }
```

Answer (score 0):

better to use with only html tag like this

```
<object data="~/img/avatar-sign.png" type="image/png">
    <img src="@Url.Content(String.Format("~/Doctor/" + doctor.DoctorID + ".png"))" />
</object>
```

or you can use likewise

```
<img src="@Url.Content(String.Format("~/Doctor/" + doctor.DoctorID + ".png"))" onerror="if (this.src != '~/img/avatar-sign.png') this.src = '~/img/avatar-sign.png';">
```